# Newton's Laws of Motion and its necessary condition

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

My question is regarding Newton's first law of motion.
The statement that everything that stays at rest stays at rest and everything that was in uniform motion stays unless an external force is applied.

And the second law stating somewhat similar to the concept which I am going to use in this question. If the net force is not zero the body of mass $m$ accelerates.

So, my question is ,

Is it true that in STATIC Equilibrium, the net force must be zero is a necessary condition but not sufficient enough to prove that whether the system is in uniform motion or not?

Since in both uniform motion and static the net force is zero has to be satisfied.

Comment: There is no difference between being static and moving with uniform speed. Everything that you will consider "static" is moving in respect to some reference frame. So, no, you don't need another condition to distinguish between the "two" situations as they are actually just one. But you may need to balance the torques as well, to ensure you do not have rotations in the system.

Comment: But also everything we consider moving is static to some reference frame so, do we need another sufficient condition to be stationary?

Comment: Not in terms of forces.

Answer (score 1):

In classical mechanics the state of uniform motion and rest state are equivalent. Meaning, you cannot distinguish between them not being provided the reference point. Linear momentum is defined up to a constant. It is a consequence of translational symmetry.

Comment: So, its true that we cannot whether a body is in motion or not if only we know is that the net force is zero, provided a reference point.

Comment: Try to reformulate your comment. It is hard to understand.

Comment: Oh sorry, I according to your answer we can't know if the body under consideration is in motion or not if we only know it's net force condition is zero.

Comment: We cannot know if the body is in uniform motion. Acceleration changes dynamic state of the system. Movement with constant velocity does not add any information into the system, unless you specify the reference frame.

Comment: Let me give you an example: if you are in a dark room with no windows sitting on the floor, would you be able to tell whether the room is in stationary state or in uniform motion (constant velocity)? No! You can only tell if it accelerates or not, you can't judge on constant speed. If you, however, have a window in that room, you can reference your room with respect to the objects in that window and make judgements about the speed.